# Get back to DataFrame after df.as_matrix()

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I play with a dataset in pandas.

At some point I use it as matrix (`df.as_matrix()`) , then I do some transformations (with `sklearn`) and I want to go back to DataFrame.

How can I go back from `df.as_matrix()` back to `df` this the most straightworward way and with preserving indexes and col names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the data frame `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(1, list('xyz'), list('abc'))

df

   a  b  c
x  1  1  1
y  1  1  1
z  1  1  1
```

`as_matrix` gives you:

```
df.as_matrix()

array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

It is completely reasonable to go back to a data frame with

```
pd.DataFrame(df.as_matrix())

   0  1  2
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1
```

But you lose the `index` and `column` information.

If you still have that info lying around

```
pd.DataFrame(df.as_matrix(), df.index, df.columns)

   a  b  c
x  1  1  1
y  1  1  1
z  1  1  1
```

And you are back where you started.